# Problems creating tables with main keys and foreign keys, why?

Tags: sql, xcode, mariadb, heidisql

I've been trying to see all the ways to make these tables, but I don't find what's wrong, because first problem appears in sintaxys, problem creating main key and problems creating foreign keys. I'd like to know if they could help me.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_ventas` (
`id_ventas` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_clientes` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_producto` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_vendedor` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`fecha` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_clientes`, `id_producto`, `id_vendedor`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;






CREATE TABLE `t_clientes` (
`id_clientes` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`apellido` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`edad` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`sexo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX `id_clientes_fkey` (`id_clientes`),
CONSTRAINT `id_clientes_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`id_clientes`) REFERENCES `t_ventas` (`id_clientes`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;





CREATE TABLE `t_productos` (
`id_producto` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`modelo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`marca` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`precio` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_proveedor` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_proveedor`),
        INDEX `id_producto_fkey` (`id_producto`),
       CONSTRAINT `id_producto_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto`) REFERENCES `t_ventas` (`id_producto`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;




CREATE TABLE `t_proveedor` (
`id_proveedor` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`apellido` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        INDEX `id_proveedor_fkey` (`id_proveedor`),
       CONSTRAINT `id_proveedor_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`id_proveedor`) REFERENCES `t_proveedor` (`id_proveedor`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;






CREATE TABLE `t_vendedor` (
`id_vendedor` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`apellido` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_sucursal` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_sucursal`),
INDEX `id_vendedor_fkey` (`id_vendedor`),
CONSTRAINT `id_vendedor_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vendedor`) REFERENCES `t_ventas` (`id_vendedor`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;





CREATE TABLE `t_sucursal` (
`id_sucursal` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        INDEX `id_sucursal_fkey` (`id_sucursal`),
       CONSTRAINT `id_sucursal_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sucursal`) REFERENCES `t_vendedor` (`id_sucursal`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I put all six tables just in case it's a problem of just one, thanks to whoever helps me...

Comment: Is it MariaDB or MySQL? Those are quite different nowadays?

Comment: What's the error message? Which statement fails?

Comment: You have multiple issues in your queries. The third query is missing comma at the end of line 6. Also a foreign key must have the same number of columns (3) than the referenced table, but you are providing a single one.

Comment: Your fourth query lacks a primary key, but you are trying to point to it with a foreign key. No can do.

Comment: It's MariaDB / HeidiSQL.

The error is:

SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'store'.' t_vendedor' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

appears to me in every table I try to create, sometimes with different message but always repeating "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" -- Read my comment above. A foreign key can point to another key of the same size (same number of columns). You are trying to point one column to three; that won't match ever.

Comment: I'm really new learning SQL, and the way I was introduced was not coded and I still don't understand much how to create the code that will open these tables... Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: I would suggest you start from scratch, running each table creation, one by one. Once you fix one, start with the next one. You have too many issues on the SQL script.

Comment: Each table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: 150 == declare the tables in a different order.